# Rating system with Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I really need help with BaaS Parse. I have a class "Person" with such fields: name, points, rating etc.
Please, help me to solve the problem - I need to set value "1" in field "rating" to user with the maximum number of points, set "2" to user with a smaller number of points and so on. How I can do it?
I know how to set "1" only for one person, who has the maximum number of points:

```
query.descending("points");
query.first({
       success: function(result){
       // ...

       },
       error: function(){
       },
 });
```

But how to do it for each person?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. 
maybe it will help someone

```
Parse.Cloud.job("Rating", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
        var usersToSave= [];
        var query = new Parse.Query("Person");
        query.descending("points");
        query.find().then(function(results) {
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                var user = results[i];
                user.set("rating", i+1);
                usersToSave.push(user);
            }
        }).then(function() {
          Parse.Object.saveAll(usersToSave, {
            success: function(list) {
                if (status) {
                    status.success("success");
                };
            }, error: function(model, error) {
                if (status) {
                    status.error(error);
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```